# Acessing a mounted partition

Tags: hard-drive

I’m new to Linux based OS. Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 13.04. I partitioned my 500 GB hard disk into 3 partitions: 70 GB root, 2 GB swap and 464 GB extended. Now I faced a new problem: I can't access the 464 GB drive. The drive is already mounted on the launch pad. When I look at the properties of that drive, it shows 463 GB as free. When I right click my mouse to create a new folder there is no option for that. Can anybody help me sort out this problem please?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu nidhin! A screenshot would be very helpful in a situation like this. Take a printscreen and upload it to http://imgur.com/, and give us the direct link to the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where exactly you right clicked, but try this.

- Go to the Home folder (you can find it on your launcher).
- On the left pane, you can find the list of your partitions.
- Click on the partition that you wish to open. The partition will be mounted and opened.
- If you already have any items in that partition, they will be displayed on the screen.
- Right click near them and you can find an option `Create New Folder`. Click it and a new folder will be created with the name `New Folder`.

Comment: i tried that..... but the option Create New Folder.is not highlighted

Answer (score 0):

If what Dineshkumar suggested doesn't work, please do the following:

1. Open a terminal (The keyboard shortcut in Unity was Ctrl+Alt+T, I think, but you can also find the terminal by opening the Dash [by clicking the top-left corner button] and typing "terminal" then clicking it from there).
2. Type "gedit /etc/fstab". (Sudo isn't needed for now)
3. Copy the contents of the file and add them to your question.

Comment: it shows a msg of No such file or directory

Comment: To the 'fstab' file, open the terminal and type `gedit /etc/fstab` (don't ignore the space between gedit and /etc).

Comment: when i enter the command gedit /etc/fstab it shows this msg

Comment: # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=ca315fb2-2500-48aa-9924-7b15adf676b9 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=02a61dce-bede-4993-a6d4-1801edf27dd7 none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: can u pls tell me what is this means?????